# Granting git fetch permissions (but not git push) on Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Which RBAC permissions control access to git fetch and git push when using a local Git repository? Is it possible (using a custom RBAC role) to grant git fetch permissions without git push permissions?

Comment: I see the "Microsoft Web Apps" resource provider, but I can't find anything that looks obviously correct there - the "Web App Source Control" resource type looks promising, but the only actions there (Read/Write/Delete) all refer to "source control configuration" rather than source control data itself.

Answer (score 1):

That is not currently supported. The RBAC situation is:

- if you're a Reader on the site, you can't access the scm site at all, and hence can't use git.
- if you're contributor or higher, you have full scm access, and can both fetch and push.

I'd suggest relying on github or bitbucket to give someone read only access to the repo.

Comment: Thanks. Which resources/permissions in Contributor make the difference here?